# React Native build signed apk Task :app:signingConfigWriterRelease FAILED

Tags: react-native, signed-apk

I am trying to build signed apk but when i tried

```
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

it throws :

```
Task :app:signingConfigWriterRelease FAILED 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signingConfigWriterRelease'.
> Trailing char < > at index 71: C:\Users\..\..\..\myProject\android\app\my-upload-key.keystore
```

SigningConfigs and buildTypes :

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

I don't know why but i can not get signed apk for a few days because of this problem.
What do i need to do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete signingConfig signingConfigs.debug inner release block

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug // try deleting this
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

gradle.properties

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-upload-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=XXXXX
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=XXXX
```

Comment: try to regenerate the keystore, you are using proguard ?

Comment: try without proguard if you can release an apk, if you see that proguard is the problem you should check all third native packages that you have in your project for check if u need a special setup for proguard.